# Can no longer upload CSR file to create an iOS certificate from my Windows machine

Tags: trigger.io

It has been awhile since I have updated my app in the App Store, so I renewed my Trigger.io subscription.

My Provisioning Profiles and Certificates are all currently expired so I generated a new CSR according to the Trigger.io documentation using the "certreq -new request.txt" command.

The problem is you can no longer upload the CSR file to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/create to generate a new certificate.  You get "Invalid CSR - Select a valid Certificate Signing Request".  This used to work for me.  Did Apple change something on their end?  I even tried changing the file extension to .certSigningRequest, and it still doesn't work.

Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: I was able to work around this issue by generating the CSR using OpenSSL.